# Why bracket a single letter in a grep regex?

Tags: regex, grep, regular-expressions

I've seen several instances where people are doing this:

```
grep [f]oobar
```

But I don't understand why that is preferable to

```
grep foobar
```

Comment: Hmm .. I thought it is supposed to match range of characters within the []. If it is just a single character, it could be just to make it look complicated :) Maybe there is something more to it.

Comment: Something so simple can be so beautiful

Answer (score 33, accepted):

There's no reason that's preferable syntax on its own. It's sometimes used as a hack when "grepping" for a process (e.g., `ps aux | grep [a]pache`). Using that syntax prevents grep from matching its own command line in the process list.

See [How to prevent "ps" reporting its own process?](https://serverfault.com/questions/367921/how-to-prevent-ps-reporting-its-own-process)

Comment: That's the only common example of that syntax I'm familiar with.

Comment: In fact, you are right.  The last several examples I ran across were from a "ps exclusion"