# Why does grepping ps [p]rocess_name exclude grep from the results

Tags: linux, grep

A cool trick that saves you from having to use grep -v when grepping ps output (yes I know pgrep exists) is to put the first letter of the process into a character class like `ps -ef |grep [s]vn`.  This will exclude the `grep svn` from being included in the output.  Why does this work?  GNU grep.

Comment: Please look at this thread ;-)

http://serverfault.com/questions/367921/how-to-prevent-ps-reporting-its-own-process/367936

Comment: Sounds totally plausible, and kind of what I figured.  If you know this is correct, put it in an answer, not a comment so I can choose it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Grep is searching for a regular expression, so for example `[Pp]rocess` will find `Process` or `process`, but an interesting side effect is that the command line of the grep operation has a `]` stuck in there, which means that the grep line doesn't contain the word `process`, it contains the word `p]rocess`, which doesn't match.

So effectively you're removing the word `process` from your grep line by putting the closing bracket in there, but still allowing it to match the word on other lines.

Answer (score 0):

Square brackets are part of grep's pattern matching. Basically `grep` gets basic regex:

[12p]rocess will expand to: 1rocess 2rocess process

Now, grep will actually search for `[1]rocess` `[2]rocess` `[p]rocess` which - as you can see - it's not `process`.

Square brackets are character class matching in regular expressions. You can read more about regualar expressions and character matching here:

http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html